# i a building Livewire laravel Gym website

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

***I have blade layout called layouts/admin-layout.blade.php***

```
@livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
<div>
{{$action}}
</div>  
{{$slot}}
@livewireScripts
</body>
```

***and my livewire component layout called livewire/list-subscribers.blade.php
and everything is working but when i use button with component the button cannot reach the addNewSubscriber function ***

```
<x-slot name="action">
    <div class="widgetbar">
        <button type="button" wire:click="addNewSubscriber"  class="btn btn-primary-rgba"><i
                class="feather icon-plus mr-2"></i>اضافة مشترك
        </button>
    </div>
</x-slot>
```

***livewire ccomponent class***

```
public function render()
    {
        $subscribers = Subscriber::with('subscription')->latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.list-subscribers', ['subscribers' => $subscribers])->layout('layouts.admin-layout');
    }
public function addNewSubscriber()
    {
        $this->showModal = false;
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('showSubscriberModal');
    }
```

***the code only working when i put the button like that by modal id ***

```
<x-slot name="action">
    <div class="widgetbar">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSubscriberModal"  class="btn btn-primary-rgba"><i
                class="feather icon-plus mr-2"></i>اضافة مشترك
        </button>
    </div>
</x-slot>
```

***when i do that the code is working and i can add correctly and opening the modal but the first syntax is not working so i want to use livewire pure not using the data-target and data-toggle***

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by adding function paranthesis:

```php
<x-slot name="action">
    <div class="widgetbar">
        <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="addNewSubscriber()"  class="btn btn-primary-rgba"><i
                class="feather icon-plus mr-2"></i>اضافة مشترك
        </button>
    </div>
</x-slot>
```